# Singular solution of the differential equation $y-2px = \tan^{-1}(xp^{2}) , p = \frac{dy}{dx}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the differential equation $$y-2px = \tan^{-1}(xp^{2}) , p = \frac{dy}{dx}\tag{1}$$

If we differentiate the above equation w.r.t $x$ and simplify, we get, $$(p+2x\frac{dp}{dx})(1+\frac{p}{1+x^{2}p^{4}})=0$$.

By putting $(p+2x\frac{dp}{dx})=0$, we will be able to find the General Solution of $(1)$.

$(1+\frac{p}{1+x^{2}p^{4}})=0$ is not considered while finding the solution because it is concerned with the singular solution of $(1)$. Why?
[image]

Comment: How is $(1)$ a differential equation? Are one or more of the symbols a derivative in disguise?

Comment: @user170231 I'm sorry, my internet connection went bad. I couldn't make the corrections. Fixed it now.

Comment: Are you just asking why $(1+\frac{p}{1+x^{2}p^{4}})=0$ is the singular solution?

Comment: @Sgg8 Of course, not. That's not a solution; that's a component equation. We used $(p+2x\frac{dp}{dx})=0$ to find the general solution but didn't consider $(1+\frac{p}{1+x^{2}p^{4}})=0$ to find the solution. Why? The reason given in my textbook is that it is concerned with the singular solution of $(1)$.

Comment: @Curiouserandcuriouser I don't think it is possible to provide an answer to your question as it is. "it is concerned with the singular solution of (1)
" has no formal meaning as far as I know and cannot be considered to be "reasoning".
$(1+\frac{p}{1+x^{2}p^{4}})=0$ clearly gives a solution to the equation. It may be a _singular_ solution if one can prove that from the definition of the singular solution

Comment: @Sgg8 //It may be a singular solution if one can prove that from the definition of the singular solution// How to prove that it yields a singular solution? Is it too complicated?

Comment: @Curiouserandcuriouser just show that this solution satisfies the definition of singular solution. Your textbook must provide that definition if it uses the term. I haven't tried to prove this, so I don't know about the difficulty, but I think it's pretty straightforward

Comment: @Sgg8 I've added an image in the question. Check the sentence marked with a pen. I didn't understand that part.

Answer (score 1):

If you replace $y(x)=v(\sqrt x)$, you get a Clairaut DE
$$
v(u)=v'(u)u+f(v'(u)),~~f(p)=\tan^{-1}(p^2/4)
$$
Then the factorization transforms to the more simple $v''(u)(u+f'(v'(u)))=0$, the regular solutions are the family of linear functions $v=Cu+f(C)$ and the second factor describes the singular solution or envelope of the regular family.

Comment: Okay, but if we don't reduce the equation to Clairaut's form, is there any way to show that $(1+\frac{p}{1+x^{2}p^{4}})=0$ describes the singular solution? If I could isolate $p$ from this equation and write it in the form $p=g(x)$, then I could substitute $g(x)$ in place of $p$ in $(1)$ to get an equation in $y$ and $x$ without any constants, i.e. singular solution. But I can't isolate $p$ from this equation. So how am I supposed to know this factor corresponds to a singular solution?